# New Acer Aspire 3 - Can I install ubuntu BEFORE letting the default WIN10 setup start?

Tags: system-installation, 19.10, acer

I have an

**Acer Aspire 3 A315-21 series Model N17Q3**

with

**Ubuntu ISO 19.10 AMD64 desktop**

My questions are:

1. Should I boot to a Ubuntu USB and install directly and never do the WIN10 setup?
2. Should I set any BIOS settings or command line parameters before I let the install of ubuntu proceed?

P.S. I assume that I might need `pci=noacpi`.

Comment: Good answer, Munsko. Suggest you make it an Answer instead of a Comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want install W10 continue too boot the Ubuntu ISO, but if you want have W10 is recomended install it first, because some say that windows dont recognize linux. The best way should be install W10 creating a partition for it(dont use all disk as partition, you will have problems to make linux partitons after), and then install ubuntu in other partition of you disk(ubuntu recognizes w10)

Answer (score 1):

SO  .. .

I called Acer support  and waited for 20+ minutes on hold.

As soon as I asked my question they dropped my call.

I called again from the same phone - 55+ minute wait (am I paranoid here?)

This time the "answer" was that changing the OS voids my warranty and the will not give tech support.

I went into the BIOS and changed

- to legacy boot.
- to allow F12 to choose boot device

Everything works great including disk encrypt

Booted